# One to one with entity framework 4.2

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am in the middle of migrating from Linq2Sql to Entity Framework and I got really stuck on one thing.

I have one table `MappingSet`. Which has a PK, `MappingSetId`. Then I also have a table `XpathMappingSet` which has the same PK, `MappingSetId`. It is both an FK and a PK.

In then I have a property on `MappingSet` which is called `XpathMappingSet`. This is null of there is no corresponding row in the `XpathMappingSet` table.

How can I configure this? I tried the following, but that didn't really work:

```
HasOptional(m => m.XpathMappingSet).WithRequired(m => m.MappingSet).Map(m => m.MapKey("MappingSetId"));
```

The exception I got was:

> (66,6) : error 0019: Each property name in a type must be unique. Property name 'MappingSetId' was already defined.

This all worked well in L2S but I cannot get it to work using Entity Framework.

MappingSet

```
public partial class MappingSet : BaseEntity
    {
        public int MappingSetId { get; set; }
        public virtual XpathMappingSet XpathMappingSet { get; set; }
    }
```

XpathMappingSet

```
public partial class XpathMappingSet
{
    public int MappingSetId { get; set; }
    public virtual MappingSet MappingSet { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping of XpathMappingSet

```
public partial class XpathMappingSetMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<XpathMappingSet>
{
    public XpathMappingSetMap()
    {
        ToTable("XpathMappingSets");

        HasKey(m => m.MappingSetId);

    }
}
```

Mapping of MappingSet

```
public partial class MappingSetMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<MappingSet>
{
    public MappingSetMap()
    {
        ToTable("MappingSets");
        HasKey(m => m.MappingSetId);
        HasOptional(m => m.XpathMappingSet).WithRequired(m => m.MappingSet).Map(m=>m.MapKey("MappingSetId"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Does EF know that MappingSetId is the PK of XPathMappingSet? Since it breaks convention, you'll need to tell EF that MappingSetId is the PK. Not sure if that will fix the prb, but it's something you should do..

Comment: @MattRoberts I use ` HasKey(m => m.MappingSetId);` on both `XpathMappingSet` and `MappingSet`

Comment: Total guess... Entity<XPathMappingSet>().HasRequired(x => x.MappingSet).WithOptional().Map(m => m.MapKey("MappingSetId")

Comment: @MattRoberts Thanks, didn't work tho :( same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I solved it.

I changed the mapping for xpathmappingset to:

```
public partial class XpathMappingSetMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<XpathMappingSet>
{
    public XpathMappingSetMap()
    {
        ToTable("XpathMappingSets");

        HasKey(m => m.XpathMappingSetId);

        Property(m => m.XpathMappingSetId).HasColumnName("MappingSetId");
    }
}
```

it didn't like the fact that it had the same name

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the column mapping part. EF figures out the mapped property is the PK.

```
HasOptional(m => m.XpathMappingSet).WithRequired(m => m.MappingSet);
```

Comment: Thanks, that was actually the first thing I tried (forgot to mention that). But I get `Invalid column name 'XpathMappingSet_MappingSetId'.`. I cannot remodel my database, so I need to tell EF the name of the column

Comment: @OskarKjellin Did you map the PK of `XpathMappingSet` using `HasKey(m => m.MappingSetId);`